# Do you need a TPU instance of Google colab when using a GCP TPU?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, tpu, gcp-ai-platform-training

I've been enjoying the free colab TPUs and I am looking to upgrade to the GCP ones, but I am a little concerned about the time limits for TPU colabs, I heard colab only allows a certain number of hours for each user.

So I am wondering if I could just use a CPU or GPU instance, and connect to the TPU on my GCP.

Comment: If you use GCP, why not just run your code there, why bother with Colab then?

Comment: I'm more used to colab/jupyter. Does GCP have a version of colab?

Comment: You might wanna check out Google Datalab then. Notebook (Jupyter but can do more than just Python) with access to GCP resources.